# Correct this javascript statement for XHTML 1 Strict

Tags: javascript, xhtml-1.0-strict

The following JavaScript was written for XHTML 1 Transitional, and the site has been moved to Strict. I'm a complete JavaScript novice, and have no idea how to correct this, could a JavaScript person help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/jquery/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        wrap: 'circular'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think something has to be corrected here?

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: Thanks Frederic - Internet Explorer tells me the error is coming from that line, and I realized the only difference was the change in doctype. Could it be something else?

Comment: Here's the error: Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 2 Apr 2013 13:50:17 UTC


Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 654
Char: 5
Code: 0
URI: http://intranet/Pages/Default.aspx

Comment: Uh, if InternetExplorer tells you a line in an error message, it could be basically anything else. Use the W3 validator.

Comment: The plugin script was loaded and executed correctly?

Comment: Thank you all for your help; I ended up dropping this code on it's own page and made an iframe - an inelegant solution. I think you all are correct, in that it may not be effected by the doctype, but has to do with the order the js files are being called, an inadvertent change in the page structure (along with the doctype).